# Rails: Find and use the id number from a diff controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to extract the id number of a unique record, that resides in a different controller as an integer, so I can save it as part of a new record in a new controller.

I can't seem to get the id to shed it's 'Array' attribute.

I've been using this:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

def incoming

  a = Group.where("name = ?", name).map { |n| n.id  }
  group_number = a.id
  puts "#{group_number} is the number!"

end
```

output is always [2] or [3] or whatever.

adding this doesn't seem to cure it

```
group_as_int = group_number.to_i
```

Lastly, the reason I'm doing all this is to save that group number as a new record in a third controller, like this:

```
Subscriber.create(:group_id => group_number, :active => "1")
or
Subscriber.create(:group_id => group_as_int, :active => "1")
```

Of course, the create balks when I try to pass an array into the create function.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to put business logic into the controller.
Try to refactor your methods and put them into your models instead.

Beside that you get the number in the following way:

```
group = Group.where("name = ?", name).first
group_number = group.id if group.present?
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks so much.  I'll also try to refactor into the model.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try `.first` to get the integer out of the array.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain from your code what you did wrong.
The first line:

```
matching_group_ids = Group.where("name = ?", name).map { |n| n.id  }
```

You called it `a`, but i prefer more verbose names. `matching_group_ids` now holds an array of id's. To get the first value of this array, the easiest solution is to just write

```
group_number = matching_group_ids[0]
```

or, more readable:

```
group_number = matching_group_ids.first
```

Mind you: you should test that the returned array is not empty.

Hope this helps.